# Github Actions cmd parameter passing in new line

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Per some tutorials, I've seen that I should be able to pass multiple parameters to Github Actions CMD with each starting in new line like example below.

```
# call sqlpackage.exe to deploy my db schema using my dacpac
- name: Update database schema using dacpac
  run: >
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\sqlpackage.exe"
      /Action:Publish
      /SourceFile:"Database.dacpac"
      /TargetServerName:"${{ secrets.SQL_Server }}"
      /TargetDatabaseName: "${{ secrets.SQL_Database }}"
      /TargetUser:"${{ secrets.SQL_User }}"
      /TargetPassword:"${{ secrets.SQL_Password }}"
      /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False
```

Unfortunately, when trying this approach, I'm facing error

> The term '/Action:Publish' is not recognized as a name of a
> | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Is there any way to use this formatting inside Github actions, or am I forced to use such formatting?

```
name: Try publishing sqlpackage
    working-directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\
    run: |
      & .\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"${{ secrets.SQL_Server }}" /TargetDatabaseName:"${{ secrets.SQL_Database }}" /SourceFile:"$Env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\northwind-dep-test\bin\Output\northwind-dep-test.dacpac" /TargetUser:"${{ secrets.SQL_User }}" /TargetPassword:"${{ secrets.SQL_Password }}" /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is a [Folded Block Scalar](https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html#block).

It folds consecutive lines like this, which is probably what you want:

```
folded: >
  line 1
  still line 1

  line 2
  still line 2
```

But it also has this peculiar feature that more-indented lines in such a block scalar lead to a linebreak

```
folded: >
  line 1
    line 2
    line 3
```

So if you remove the extra spaces before the following lines, it should work how you want, e.g.

```
  run: >
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\sqlpackage.exe"
    /Action:Publish
    more arguments...
```